# how get attribute relation from another entity class Java Persistance API and show to JSP through servlet?

Tags: class, jpa, ejb, entity

I have 2 entities are entities meeting and meetingAgenda.

I write code entity class (EJB) from database like this.

```
public class Meeting implements Serializable {
......
 @XmlTransient
    public Collection<MeetingAgenda> getMeetingAgendaCollection() {
        return meetingAgendaCollection;
    }

    public void setMeetingAgendaCollection(Collection<MeetingAgenda> meetingAgendaCollection) {
        this.meetingAgendaCollection = meetingAgendaCollection;
    }
.......
}
```

and entity class meeting agenda like this.
.....

```
public class MeetingAgenda implements Serializable {
....
    public String getAgenda() {
        return agenda;
    }
    public void setAgenda(String agenda) {
        this.agenda = agenda;
    }
....
}
```

method getMeetingAgendaCollection is a relation from meeting entity . then, in my controller servlet i call EJB like this.

```
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private RapatFacadeLocal rapatFacade;

public void init() throws ServletException { 
        // store category list in servlet context      
   getServletContext().setAttribute("meetings", rapatFacade.findAll());
}
......
```

i want to show data from table entities meeting and meetingAgenda...but  i can't..
please help..

i write code in JSP page.. like this..

```
 <c:forEach var="meeting" items="${meetings}">
<td> MeetingCode :  ${meeting.meetingCode} </td>
<td> Meeting :  ${meeting.meeting} </td>
<td> Agenda :  ${meeting.getMeetingAgendaCollection} </td> 
</c:forEach>
```

**how do I display data Agenda using getMeetingAgendaCollection  ????**

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution,
in my controller servlet

```
  Rapat selectedMeeting = rapatFacade.find(Long.parseLong(id));
                     request.setAttribute("meetingDetails",selectedMeeting); 


  Collection<RapatAgenda> agenda = selectedMeeting.getRapatAgendaCollection();
                     request.setAttribute("meetingAgendas", agenda);
```

in my JSP client

```
.... 
<c:forEach var="agenda" items="${meetingAgendas}"> 
  <td> ${agenda.agenda}  </td>
 </c:forEach>
...
```

but I found the problem further.
 if I want to display another entity (one to many) that relate to entities meeting.
i write code like this.

```
Rapat selectedMeeting = rapatFacade.find(Long.parseLong(id));
                     request.setAttribute("meetingDetails",selectedMeeting); 

 Collection<RapatAgenda> agenda = selectedMeeting.getRapatAgendaCollection();
                     request.setAttribute("meetingAgendas", agenda);

 Unit selectUnit = unitFacade.find(selectedMeeting.getUnitInisiatorId());
                     request.setAttribute("initiator", selectUnit);
```

i wont selectedMeeting.getUnitInisiatorId() value is integer  , 
if i write manually,

```
Unit selectUnit = unitFacade.find(Long.parseLong(1));
                         request.setAttribute("initiator", selectUnit);
```

problem solved..

```
what selectedMeeting.getUnitInisiatorId() syntax is correct ..?
```

please help.. thank you..

Comment: I finally found the solution again.